# Python to compare huge text files based on multiple keys

Tags: python

I have two text files each of approximately 1GB where each line has 60 columns in it.
There are 6 columns which are keys to compare in each file.

Example :

> **file1**:
>   `4|null|null|null|null|null|3590740374739|20077|7739662|75414741|`
>
> **file2**: 
>   `4|null|11|333|asdsd|null|3590740374739|20077|7739662|75414741|`

Here two lines are equal as columns 7,8,9 and 10 are same in two files (keys).
I tried a sample to compare files without considering keys, which works fine, but I need to compare based on the keys, not character to character in each line.

Here is the code sample I worked to compare without considering keys.

```
matched = open('matchedrecords.txt','w')

with open('srcone.txt') as b:
  blines = set(b)

with open('srctwo.txt') as a:
  alines = set(a)

with open('notInfirstSource.txt', 'w') as result:
  for line in alines:
    if line not in blines:
      result.write(line)
    else:
      matched.write(line)       

with open('notInsecondSource.txt', 'w') as non:
    for lin in blines:
      if lin not in alines:
        non.write(lin)

matched.close()
```

Comment: Could the same keys appear twice (on otherwise different lines) within a file? If so, what should happen in that case?

Comment: The basic method to use here is to sort both files and walk through them simultaneously. Besides the heavy sorting operation that's just a linear (walk through it once) function.

Comment: Thanks for the comment:) .Combinations of keys are unique in both files @TimPietzcker.Because one of the key is a date timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the way you can compare the lines based on keys/columns but I am not sure how efficient it is.

```
 matched =open('matchedrecords.txt','w')
    with open('srcone.txt') as b:
      blines = set(b)
    with open('srctwo.txt') as a:
      alines= set(a)

        # List of columns or keys to compare
        list_of_columns_to_compare=[7,8,9]

        a_columns=[]
        b_columns=[]

        for blin in blines :
           for alin in alines:
               for column_no in list_of_columns_to_compare :
                   # Appending columns  to a list to compare
                   b_columns.append(blin.split('|')[column_no])
                   a_columns.append(alin.split('|')[column_no])

                   if a_columns == b_columns:
                       matched.write(blin + " = " + alin)
```

Comment: Hello @RBH  Thanks for your answer:)..i tried with 300 Mb data and its taking so much time,as there are huge number of iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a cue from a [recipe for KeyedSets](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576932-sets-with-a-custom-equalityuniqueness-function/) on ActiveState, you can build a set and then simply use set intersection and set difference to produce your results:

```
import collections

class Set(collections.Set):
    @staticmethod
    def key(s): return tuple(s.split('|')[6:10])
    def __init__(self, it): self._dict = {self.key(s):s for s in it}
    def __len__(self): return len(self._dict)
    def __iter__(self): return self._dict.itervalues()
    def __contains__(self, value): return self.key(value) in self._dict

data = {}
for filename in 'srcone.txt', 'srctwo.txt':
    with open(filename) as f:
        data[filename] = Set(f)

with open('notInFirstSource.txt', 'w') as f:
    for lines in data['srctwo.txt'] - data['srcone.txt']:
        f.write(''.join(lines))

with open('notInSecondSource.txt', 'w') as f:
    for lines in data['srcone.txt'] - data['srctwo.txt']:
        f.write(''.join(lines))

with open('matchedrecords.txt', 'w') as f:
    for lines in data['srcone.txt'] & data['srctwo.txt']:
        f.write(''.join(lines))
```

Comment: Hey ROb ...can you please explain me the _init_ function written above .And actually unique keys that to be compared cannot be in serial,I mean it is like (6,7,9,11,14)

Answer (score 0):

Finally ,i could achieve this in very less time using dictionaries.
i.e  a 370 MB data compared to 270 MB data file in 50 Seconds Maximum(Using a tuple as a key ).
This is the script :

```
   reader = open("fileA",'r')
    reader2 = open("fileB",'r')
    TmpDict ={}
    TmpDict2={}
    for line in reader:
        line = line.strip()
        TmpArr=line.split('|')
       #Forming a dictionary with below columns as keys
        TmpDict[TmpArr[2],TmpArr[3],TmpArr[11],TmpArr[12],TmpArr[13],TmpArr[14]]=line
    for line in reader2:
        line = line.strip()
        TmpArr=line.split('|')
        TmpDict2[TmpArr[2],TmpArr[3],TmpArr[11],TmpArr[12],TmpArr[13],TmpArr[14]]=line
    outfile = open('MatchedRecords.txt', 'w')
    outfileNonMatchedB=open('notInB','w')
    outfileNonMatchedA=open('notInA','w')
    for k,v in TmpDict.iteritems():
        if k in TmpDict2:
            outfile.write(v+ '\n')
        else:
            outfileNonMatchedB.write(v+'\n')
    outfile.close()
    outfileNonMatchedB.close()
    for k,v in TmpDict2.iteritems():
        if k not in TmpDict:
            outfileNonMatchedA.write(v+'\n')
    outfileNonMatchedA.close()
```

Any improvements could be done to this ? Suggest me !
Thanks